# Change the background color of exposed dropdown menu

Tags: android, drop-down-menu, material-design, spinner

I think Android developers are kidding us. First they removed the real spinner from the Material Design and second it is somehow impossible to style. Look at this image. I looks really good ALMOST!. I did not find a possibility to change the background color of the dropdown list. I can style each item in the list, but that still leaves the 'rounded corners area' on top and bottom of the list in white.

[image]

Does anybody know how to ONLY change the background color of the list?

There is indeed a way of changing it (Taken from [here](https://medium.com/@rmirabelle/there-is-no-material-design-spinner-for-android-3261b7c77da8)), by applying:

```
 <style name="AppTheme.ExposedDropdownMenu" parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox.ExposedDropdownMenu">
    <item name="materialThemeOverlay">@style/AppTheme.ExposedDropdownMenu.MaterialThemeOverlay</item>
 </style>


 <style name="AppTheme.ExposedDropdownMenu.MaterialThemeOverlay" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- background color of dropdown (popup) items -->
    <item name="colorSurface">#444444</item>
 </style>
```

But this changes the padding, color, padding of the EditText. Also it completly removes the elevation of the menu, which i was not able to restore.

It cannot be so difficult to only change the background color of this menu?! Why is this API so damn confusing.

Follow up question: Anyone knows a way of making the TextView compund drawable round (Inside the EditText)?

Comment: Have you found a solution? I am looking for this right now!

Comment: Hi it works as expected from the link you have posted. Just copy paste all the code as it is! And change values according to your need!! I am sure you will find the solution if you follow the article. Paste all the code not half of it!

Comment: In order to add elevation to pop up add this: `<item name="android:popupElevation">8dp</item>` inside: `<style name="AppTheme.ExposedDropdownMenu.MaterialThemeOverlay"
        parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.DarkActionBar">`

Comment: Can you share sources?

Answer (score 0):

```
<style name="changeBackgroundColor"  parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.Outline   dBox.Dense">
<item name="colorSurface">@color/yourColor</item>
</style>
```

Then, include this theme in your .xml layout inside TextInputLayout. i.e.

```
android:theme="@style/changeBackgroundColor"
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this line " 8dp" for  Elevation to popup.inside style :

```
 <style name="AppTheme.ExposedDropdownMenu.MaterialThemeOverlay" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- background color of dropdown (popup) items -->
        <item name="colorSurface">@4f4f4f</item>
        <item name="android:popupElevation">8dp</item>
    </style>
```

use this sytle inside main style like:

```
<style name="dropdown" parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox.ExposedDropdownMenu">
<!-- The color of the label when it is collapsed and the text field is active -->
<item name="colorControlActivated">@color/colorFFB44C</item>
<item name="materialThemeOverlay">@style/AppTheme.ExposedDropdownMenu.MaterialThemeOverlay</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

Cool article about this: https://medium.com/itnext/styling-material-exposed-dropdown-menus-on-android-19c7d21a9fcc

If short:

1. Create drawable for background (dropdown_background.xml for example)

   ```
    <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <solid android:color="@color/your_color" />
    <corners android:radius="16dp" />
   ```
2. In AutoCompleteTextView set:

   android:dropDownSelector="@drawable/dropdown_background"
3. In your fragment in onViewCreated set background to your AutoCompleteTextView, something like this:

   ```
    binding.YOUR_AutoCompleteTextView_ID.apply {
    setDropDownBackgroundDrawable(
        ResourcesCompat.getDrawable(
            resources,
            R.drawable.language_dropdown_bg,
            null
        )
    )
    setAdapter(adapter)
   ```

   }

Answer (score 0):

Items from dropdown are rendered outside the dropdown element itself, they are rendered on external surface. This is the reason why changing properies of this elements dosn't work. This is why changing the theme value of colorSurface works.